# API Data is not being added to my dictionary correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, loops, espn

API: https://gist.github.com/nntrn/ee26cb2a0716de0947a0a4e9a157bc1c#v2sportsfootballleaguesnflseasonsyeartypesseasontypeweeksweeknumevents

Chosen API Link: https://sports.core.api.espn.com/v2/sports/football/leagues/nfl/seasons/2022/types/2/weeks/16/events

From this API, I am attempting to extract 12 pieces of data for each team (32 teams), so that I can plug those numbers into a formula and predict the winners of matchups. I created a dictionary to format how I want to store the data here: https://pastebin.com/cK1wJ0ZS (Teams are represented by their "id" in the index) Their ID is assigned in the API.

When I run my data extract file ( https://pastebin.com/LwGus277 ), 60 entries are entered into the categories I have written. This is coming from the loop in my `fill_game()` method. I do not understand why all 60 are coming through.

```
for game in range(len(games["items"])):
     self.fill_home_team(games["items"][game]["$ref"])
```

Each list's length inside of my sub-categories should be equal to the last_games param of `__init__`, but it is 60 now.

If last_games was 1, then there would only be 1 week's worth of games, and since each team plays once per week, there should be 1 piece of data per category.

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

I've gone through and followed the instructions line by line as if I was the computer, and still could not understand how these numbers were being looped in.

EDIT: I have tried debugging these lines in PyCharm:

```
    # Add Turnover Differential
    self.stats[team_id - 1][0]["Turnover Differential"].append(path[10]["stats"][39]["value"])

    # Add RedZone Efficiency
    self.stats[team_id - 1][1]["RedZone Efficiency"].append(path[10]["stats"][12]["value"])

    # Add Third Down Attempts
    self.stats[team_id - 1][2]["Third Down Attempts"].append(path[10]["stats"][29]["value"])
```

I noticed that instead of putting the team's data in their respective index at [team_id - 1], it is appending the data to EVERY team's list. I cannot figure out why that is happening. Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some debugging and can understand why it gave you 60 entries because each week contains the following number of games,

[image]

Thus, 16 + 16 + 13 + 15 = 60

The issue is when you initialise the stats object,

change from

```
self.stats = [n for i in range(32)]
```

to

```
self.stats = [[
            {"Turnover Differential": []},  # 0
            {"RedZone Efficiency": []},  # 1
            {"Third Down Attempts": []},  # 2
            {"Third Down Conversions": []},  # 3
            {"Fourth Down Attempts": []},  # 4
            {"Fourth Down Conversions": []},  # 5
            {"Kickoff Yards": []},  # 6
            {"Kickoff Attempts": []},  # 7
            {"Kick Return Yards": []},  # 8
            {"Kick Return Attempts": []},  # 9
            {"Punt Yards": []},  # 10
            {"Punt Attempts": []},  # 11
        ] for i in range(32)]
```

The previous code gives you 32 references to the same object n (updating one will show the changes in all the items), whereas the new code gives you 32 distinct (independent) objects.

Comment: You are 100% on the right track, thank you so much for taking the time to debug!

To help you understand what I need as an output, let me explain a bit more.

That loop that you deleted loops through each game's link being played that week. Each game has two "competitors" (home team and away team). 
I am taking each team's "id" from the API and using that to index in my stats array (0-31). 
For example, the first link in the loop is JAX@NYJ. I want to grab all the data for NYJ since they are home, and then loop to the next link, find the home team, and repeat for 16 games (or len(games))

Comment: Team IDs start at 1, and go to 32 (they skip 31 and 32, and go to 33, and 34., but this is already accounted for). team_id - 1 maps it to the correct index. The issue is that the data that should be at team_id - 1 is being filled out for EVERY index (0-32) and repeats for each game. It will not only fill out all data for that team's index that I provided. That is my issue.

Comment: @Raylo, I have updated my answer. Your investigation also helped to identify the issue. High-five to both of us!